# In Data Lake architecture, is there a way to store or flag bad or unclean data?

Tags: azure, bigdata, azure-data-lake, delta-lake

We're building out a lakehouse over top an Azure Data Lake Gen 2, and we're interested that either "pulls out" or "flags" bad data from our pipelines.

Are there any industry best practices or case studies we can look at to replicate when we go to design this? Are there any unique features or services within the Azure ecosystem (specifically within Azure Synapse) that can help us achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you define “bad” data, exactly?

Comment: @Dai we likely would have custom rules for each field that we're interested in curating. For example, a field representing weights would only allow positive numbers, no more than X lbs.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is handling bad data in Azure Data Lake Gen2
Azure Data Factory(ETL) to copy data from source systems into your data lake,
And configure a data validation step in your pipeline to identify and flag bad data before it is ingested into the lake.
You can use tools like Azure Databricks as you said you are having the Bigdata Databricks would be a good option for Cleanising,Transforming.
In azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 the feature of  hierarchical namespace to store bad data in a separate folder from good data.
This approach allows you to keep bad data separate from the rest of your data, and makes it easier to locate and delete it when necessary.

For example In DataBricks we have Below Techniques will do Error Handling and write them in ADLS Gen2

•   PERMISSIVE: replaces null value to the corrupt record and adds an addition column _corrupt_record with the corrupt row value.

ex:`df2=spark.read.option("mode","PERMISSIVE").csv("/FileStore/tables/new_insurance_data.csv",header=True,schema=myschema2)`

•   DROPMALFORMED: drop the corrupt records from the dataframe.

ex:`df3=spark.read.option("mode","DROPMALFORMED").csv("/FileStore/tables/new_insurance_data.csv",header=True,schema=myschema2)`
•   FAILFAST: Fails the command if any corrupt records are present in the data.

ex:`df4=spark.read.option("mode","FAILFAST").csv("/FileStore/tables/new_insurance_data.csv",header=True,schema=myschema2)`

•   badRecordsPath: Drops the corrupt record from the dataframe and stores the corrupt records to the specified path.

ex:`df5=spark.read.option("badRecordsPath","/demo/").csv("/FileStore/tables/new_insurance_data.csv",header=True,schema=myschema2)`

I have performed these above steps in the databricks
To check the Files in the databricks

```
dbutils.fs.ls("/FileStore/tables")

. This is the path for the CSV file.
df=spark.read.csv('/FileStore/tables/sales.csv')
```

[image]

[image]

from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, StringType

```
dfschema = StructType([

StructField('id', IntegerType(), False),

StructField('name', StringType(), False),

StructField('Salesamnt', IntegerType(), False),

StructField('PayType', StringType(), False),

StructField('_Corrupt_rec', StringType(), True)

])
```

Reconsructing the Schema.

[image]

**1st Method.**

```
df1=(spark.read.option("mode", "PERMISSIVE").csv('/FileStore/tables/sales.csv',header='True',schema=dfschema))
```

[image]

**2nd Method.**
. DROPMALFORMED will drop the records

```
df2=(spark.read.option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED").csv('/FileStore/tables/sales.csv',header='True',schema=dfschema))
```

[image]

**3rd method.**
.If there are any ERROR records the FAILFAST will stop the execution.
d`f3=(spark.read.option("mode", "FAILFAST").csv('/FileStore/tables/sales.csv',header='True',schema=dfschema))`

. Creating Bad Records Path for the bad data.

```
df3=(spark.read.option("badRecordsPath", "/FileStore/tables/demo/").csv('/FileStore/tables/sales.csv',header='True',schema=dfschema))
```

[image]

Once the data is in transformed then it wrtten in to ADLS GEN2 and from there it will moved to synapse using ADF.

And also would Like to let you know as you asked specifically in Azure synapse as per my experience I have handled the big data transformation and Clensing the data and writing the Curated data into Azure synpase(target).